# Embed Formatting Inline

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The current embed I have looks like this:

[image: myEmbed]

However, I want the sections named `Total` to be in the same line. I'm not sure how you break the inline without the second `Total` not being in the same line as well.

The result I'm looking for:

[image: exampleEmbed]

My current code:

```js
//ignore the card[1], card[0], etc. Those are arrays for what I want to post as emoji's/card values
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Blackjack`)
  //card[1] = rank; card[0] = suit
  .addFields(
    { name: 'Your Hand', value: `${card[1]}${card[0]}${card3[1]}${card3[0]}`, inline: true },
    { name: "Dealer's Hand", value : `${card2[1]}${card2[0]}`, inline: true },
    { name: "Total: [calculate later]", value: "\u200B" },
    { name: "Total: [to create later]", value: "\u200B", inline: true },
  )
  .setFooter("Commands\n!stand\n!hit\n!double\n!fold\n!split"); 
message.channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to add the total value in the same column by including it in the hands' value on the next line after the cards. You could also add some extra space between the two columns:

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle(`Blackjack`).addFields(
  {
    name: 'Your Hand',
    value: `A♦2♠7♦\n\nTotal: **10/20**`,
    inline: true,
  },
  {
    name: '\b',
    value: '\b',
    inline: true,
  },
  {
    name: "Dealer's Hand",
    value: `K♦4♣\n\nTotal: **14**`,
    inline: true,
  },
);
message.channel.send(embed);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **both** field's `inline` option to `true`. Keep in mind that the result may be different on different sized screens

```
{ name: "Total: [calculate later]", value: "\u200B", inline: true},
{ name: "Total: [to create later]", value: "\u200B", inline: true},
```

Comment: But then it'll end up in the same line as `Your Hand` and `Dealer's Hand`